# Can someone help me on the makeMove method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game class and one of the problem is the makeMove method in which I have to use the switch method. When I use the tester class it is not working. Can someone show me what the answer/problem should be.
Here is the tic tac toe class

```
public class TicTacToe
{
private String[][] board;
private int turn;
private boolean hasWinner;
private boolean bale;
/**
 * Constructs an empty game board.  Sets the turn to zero.
 */
public TicTacToe()
{
    board = new String[][] {
        {"1", " | ", "2", " | ", "3"},
        {"-", "-|-", "-", "-|-", "-"},
        {"4", " | ", "5", " | ", "6"},
        {"-", "-|-", "-", "-|-", "-"},
        {"7", " | ", "8", " | ", "9"},
    };
    turn = 0;
}

/**
 * Prints the two dimensional array gameboard to the console with an empty line before and after
 */
public void drawBoard()
{


            for(int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++)
            {
                for( int cols = 0; cols < board[0].length; cols++)
                {
                    System.out.print(board[rows][cols] );
                }
                System.out.println();


            }


     }

   /**
 * Precondition: the location will be a number 1 through 9
 * Hint: Loop through the array and see if the number still exists there.
 * @param location the numeric location according to the initial configuration
 * @return true if the space is unoccupied and legal, false otherwise
 */
public boolean validMove(int location)
{
       for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board[0].length; col++) {

               if( board[row][col].equals( location))
               {
                   bale = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    bale = true;
                }

         }

     }
           return bale;     
   }








/**
 * Preconditions: the location is valid, the symbol is a single character: X or O.
 * @param location the numeric location according to the initial configuration
 * @param symbol the player's symbol
 */
public void makeMove(int location, String symbol)
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    //map the numeric location to the row and column on the game board
    switch(location)
    {
        case 1: row = 0; col = 0; break;
        case 2: row = 0; col = 2; break;
        /*#
         * Insert the rest of the cases below.  More info on switch statements here:
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html
         * One use is to replace a long series of if/else if/else statements.
         */
         case 3: row = 0; col = 1; break;
          case 4: row = 2; col = 0; break;
           case 5: row = 2; col = 2; break;
            case 6: row = 2; col = 1; break;
             case 7: row = 1; col = 0; break;
              case 8: row = 1; col = 2; break;
               case 9: row = 1; col = 1; break;
    }
    /*#
     * Insert the symbol in the appropriate location below
     */
    location = symbol;


}
/**
 * Checks if the winning condition has been met for either player.
 * @return true if there is a winner, false otherwise
 */
public boolean hasWinner()
{
    /*#
     * if there is a winner from hasWinner("X") or hasWinner("O"), return true
     * otherwise false
     */
    hasWinner = false; 

   for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i+=2) 
   {
       if ((board[i][0].equals("X") == true) && (board[i][2].equals("X") == true) && (board[i][4].equals("X") == true))
       {
            hasWinner = true;  

       } 
       else if ((board[i][0].equals("O") == true) && (board[i][2].equals("O") == true) && (board[i][4].equals("O") == true))
       {
            hasWinner = true;  

       } 
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i+=2) 
   {
       if ((board[0][i].equals("X") == true) && (board[2][i].equals("X") == true) && (board[4][i].equals("X") == true))
       {
           hasWinner = true; 

       }  
       else if ((board[0][i].equals("O") == true) && (board[2][i].equals("O") == true) && (board[4][i].equals("O") == true))
       {
           hasWinner = true; 

       }  
   }      

   if( (board[0][0].equals("X")==true) && (board[2][2].equals("X")==true) && (board[4][4].equals("X") == true)) 
   {
       hasWinner = true;

   }
   else if( (board[0][0].equals("O")==true) && (board[2][2].equals("O")==true) && (board[4][4].equals("O") == true)) 
   {
       hasWinner = true;

   }

   if( (board[4][4].equals("X")==true) && (board[2][2].equals("X")==true) && (board[0][0].equals("X") == true)) 
   {
       hasWinner = true;

   }
   else if( (board[4][4].equals("O")==true) && (board[2][2].equals("O")==true) && (board[0][0].equals("O") == true)) 
   {
       hasWinner = true;

   }

   return hasWinner; 
}

/**
 * @param symbol the symbol of the player to check for a win condition
 * @return true if there is a winner, false otherwise
 */
private boolean hasWinner(String symbol)
{
    /*#
     * return true if there are three of symbol in a row vertically, horizontally, or diagonally
     * hint: there is a gap of one string between each actual occupiable space, so when looping,
     * you can change your updater from i++ to i+=...well, I'll leave it to you to figure out what
     * number to use after the +=. 
     */


    return true;

}

/**
 * For debugging and testing only.
 * @param state a valid board configuration
 */
public void setGameState(String[][] state)
{
    board = state;
}

}
```

and here is the tester class

```
public class TicTacToeTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TicTacToe t = new TicTacToe();
    t.drawBoard();
    System.out.println("Expected: \n\n1 | 2 | 3\n--|---|--\n4 | 5 | 6\n--|---|--\n7 | 8 | 9\n\n");
    System.out.println(t.validMove(4));
    System.out.println("Expected: true");
    t.makeMove(4, "X");
    t.drawBoard();
    System.out.println("Expected: \n\n1 | 2 | 3\n--|---|--\nX | 5 | 6\n--|---|--\n7 | 8 | 9\n\n");
    System.out.println(t.validMove(4));
    System.out.println("Expected: false");
    t.makeMove(9, "O");
    t.drawBoard();
    System.out.println("Expected: \n\n1 | 2 | 3\n--|---|--\nX | 5 | 6\n--|---|--\n7 | 8 | O\n\n");
}
}
```

Also I tried mutliple times and days to do this, but the code is not does what it is supposed to be expected to do

Comment: What do you expect and not get? The results seems fair to me, I cant see anything unexpected based on your print outs

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `location=symbol;`,you are trying to convert string to int.If u want to do so,then use either `Integer.parseInt() or Integer.valueOf()`,but be warned even then,you will get `NumberFormtException`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's this line which doesn't compile, because you're assigning a String to an int:

```
location = symbol;
```

I assume you meant to do this here?

```
board[row][col] = symbol;
```

---

Then, your indexes in the switch statement are off. For example, `9` should translate to row 4 and column 4:

[image: Row and column indexes]

---

And on a final note, where you're writing things like...

```
if(board[i][0].equals("X") == true)
```

... you can just write them as...

```
if(board[i][0].equals("X"))
```

... and get the same behaviour. If statements execute the code in the body if the expression in them evaluates to true. You're doing an extra step that doesn't do anything, because comparing any boolean value to `true` just returns the boolean value you had.

Comment: thanks for the help and advice, it is much appreciated and the code finally work. Thank you